# Use lazy loaded components in parent module?

Tags: angular, angular5

I have a parent modules(app.module) & a child module(contacts.module). The child module is lazy loaded.  The parent module utilizes a component from the child module but when I navigate to the child route I get the error:

```
'app-contacts-home' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-contacts-home' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-contacts-home' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to
```

Obviously that component isn't part of the parent module since it's being lazy loaded.  I tried adding `app-contacts-home` as an  `entryComponent` in contacts.module but had no luck.

How can I use a lazy loaded component in my parent component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't use a component from a child lazy load module in a parent module.

What you should do in these situations is to make a 3rd module (SharedModule) that will have the component that is used in components from both modules. Then import that 3rd module in parent and child module, that 3rd module won't be lazy loaded.

The documentation in this page https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules have useful information about that.

Hope that this helps!